# Как получить lsh из ORB дескрипторов?

Tags: opencv

OpenCV начал учить недавно. Как я могу получить список хешей из matcher'а, в которого я внёс дескрипторы `ORB`?

Привожу код, интересуют строки:

```
1. // matcher_->getListOfLsh(); 

2. // Могу я как-то получить список хешей "qgdlfospahs"....
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread("categories2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = ORB::create();
    cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> descriptor = ORB::create();

    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints1;
    detector->detect(img1, keypoints1);
    std::cout << "find "«keypoints1.size() << " keypoints in img1"
        << std::endl;

    cv::Mat descriptors1;
    descriptor->compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);

    cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher> matcher_;
    matcher_ = new cv::FlannBasedMatcher(
        new cv::flann::LshIndexParams(5, 24, 2));

    // по идее, тут уже должны появиться индексы в виде хешей
    matcher_->add(descriptors1);

    //matcher_->getListOfLsh(); что-то на подобие

    //Могу я как-то получить список хешей
    //"qgdlfospahsy24sa6nhss65s7hns7" для ORB дескрипторов?

    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```